# Xcode 10 Storyboard image rendering

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode10

I initially built my project in Xcode 9.3 and updgraded Xcode to 10 . After which all the images in the storyboard look very big. Storyboard renders 3x images by default and the layout looks bad. However everythings fine when the application is run on phone.

How i can reset the storyboard to render appropriate images.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot for the same.

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I have added the image

Answer (score 1):

There are possible few reasons:

1. Views added without the constraints. If so, you should enable and set up the views with the constraints.
2. Image views have `Content Mode` different than `Aspect Fit`. Set `Aspect Fit` mode.
3. Image views have bigger value of height constraint than cells' height. You should set the views height dependent on superview height.